# SCTP port is not opening to receive traffic from outside of kubernetes cluster

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I have a cluster with two machines (1 master and 1 worker) and have a single pod on worker node which is providing SCTP service. A **ClusterIP** service related to the pod declares **externalIPs**. The value of externalIPs is the public IP (###.###.##.208) of the worker's machine. When pod and service are deployed using helm I can see both pod and service are available and external IP is assigned to the service but result of netstat command shows that port defined for sctp service is not opened to be accessed from outside world, however if I do the same thing for a tcp port it gets opened for the outside world. Result of netstat is given as below -

**For SCTP -**

*user1@master:~/build/helm$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces*

NAMESPACE NAME TYPE CLUSTER-IP EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S) AGE

default amf-service ClusterIP 10.99.154.48 ###.###.##.208 38412/SCTP 2m55s

*user1@worker01:~$ netstat -nl | grep 38412*

<doesn't return anything>

**For TCP -**

*user1@master:~/build/helm$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces*

NAMESPACE NAME TYPE CLUSTER-IP EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S) AGE

default amf-service ClusterIP 10.99.154.48 ###.###.##.208 38412/TCP 2m16s

*user1@worker01:~$ netstat -nl | grep 38412*

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State

tcp 0 0 ###.###.##.208:38412 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN

**Service Definition -**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: amf-service
  labels:
    {{- include "amf-chart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
#######    - port: {{ .Values.service.http_port }}
#######      targetPort: {{ .Values.service.http_port }}
#######     protocol: TCP
#######     name: http
    - port: {{ .Values.service.sctp_port }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.service.sctp_port }}
      protocol: SCTP
      name: sctp
  selector:
    {{- include "amf-chart.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
  externalIPs:
    - { .Values.service.workerIP}
```

It should have behaved same as that of TCP and service should be available at port 38412 for SCTP protocol.

For reproduction deploy a pod which provides sctp service and use the service configuration as I have mentioned in service template given above.

***If I run the SCTP client inside the cluster in a pod I am able to use SCTP service.***

**Environment:**

Kubernetes version (use kubectl version): *1.21*

Cloud provider or hardware configuration: *OS (e.g: cat /etc/os-release): Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)*
Kernel (e.g. uname -a): *Linux worker01 5.4.0-72-generic #80~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 23:26:25 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

Network plugin and version (if this is a network-related bug): *`{ "name": "cbr0", "cniVersion": "0.3.1", "plugins": [ { "type": "flannel", "delegate": { "hairpinMode": true, "isDefaultGateway": true } }, { "type": "portmap", "capabilities": { "portMappings": true } } ] }`*

Others: *Docker container is using centos8 as base image (FROM centos:centos8)*

Comment: Do you use cloud provider or bare metal instances ?
Can you provide the output of `lsmod | grep sctp` command ?
Does the command `netstat --sctp` return any errors ?

Comment: @matt_j details no cloud provider is used it is on VM. Rest of the details are provided below

Comment: lsmod | grep sctp

sctp 344064 25
xt_sctp 20480 5
libcrc32c 16384 6
nf_conntrack,nf_nat,btrfs,xfs,ip_vs,sctp
x_tables 45056 16 ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,xt_statistic,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_nat,xt_comment,ip6_tables,xt_sctp,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,ip6table_mangle,xt_MASQUERADE,iptable_mangle,xt_mark

Comment: netstat --sctp: 

no Local and Foreign addresses are assigned, but no error message is reported.
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State

Comment: I have no issue with reaching out the SCTP server from outside my cluster with workers based on Ubuntu Focal (20.4). I see you've created an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/102646) on github so I suggest you continue there.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use Calico instead of flannel with NodeIP in place of ClusterIP.